# ESP8266 - MAX3485 Modbus not getting data

Tags: esp8266, rs485, modbus

I'm trying to connect a modbus meter to a nodeMcu LoLin v3

I'm using a MAX3485 module to transfer the TTL to a RS485 connection.
The modbus server has unitId 1, baud rate 9600 and no Parity

This is the scheme. A e B from the module go to the modbus server device
[image: Connection]

And this is my simple script

```
#define DIRECTION D3

#include <ModbusRTU.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial S(D2, D1);
ModbusRTU mb;

bool cb(Modbus::ResultCode event, uint16_t transactionId, void* data) { // Callback to monitor errors
  if (event != Modbus::EX_SUCCESS) {
    Serial.print("Error result: 0x");
    Serial.println(event, HEX);
    
  } else {
    Serial.print("No Error");
  }
  return true;
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(DIRECTION, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(DIRECTION, 0);
  S.begin(9600, SWSERIAL_8N1);
  
  mb.begin(&S);
  
  mb.client();
}

void loop() {
  uint16_t res[2];

  if (!mb.slave()) {    // Check if no transaction in progress
    mb.readHreg(1, 5, res, 1, cb); // Send Read Hreg from Modbus Server
    while (mb.slave()) { // Check if transaction is active
      mb.task();
      delay(10);
      
    }
    Serial.println("Res");
    Serial.println(res[0]);
    Serial.println(res[1]);
    
  }
  delay(1000);
}
```

I created a Software Serial on D1 and D2 and i'm trying to read from it but no matter what i do, i keep getting error 4 from the response and 2 values in my reg array i do not where they come from...

```
Error result: 0xE4
Res
59044
16382
```

Am I missing something?
The modbus server works because i connected it to another client and everything is ok

Comment: If you're using a MAX**3**485 then VCC should be connected to 3.3V, not VIN (which on some boards cannot provide power but instead can only be used to power the board itself).

Comment: You might find my answer to [this question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/86154/how-do-i-find-out-the-maximum-current-through-vin-on-a-nodemcu-board/86155#86155) enlightening...

Comment: i do not know if it's 3.3V or 5V... i put it on 3.3V on the ESP8266, nothing changes, it's still powered on